# Numpy count rows in one column in DataFrame without copying

Tags: python, pandas

```
source_pos = get_list_index_or_none(col_list, SOURCE_COLUMN)
# This line below makes copy of the column and allocates 
# additional memory, which is not ideal
source_only = filtered_df.iloc[:, source_pos:source_pos + 1:].iloc[:, 0]

rows_with_many_words_in_source = source_only.astype(str).str.count(
    ' ') + 1 > SOURCE_WORDS_LIMIT
```

I want to count the amount of rows that has a string that consists of multiple words (i.e. contains a space) in a specific column. How can I do that without allocating memory for `pd.Series`, like it does in the example code?

This is memory usage before that line:

```
2022-07-29 12:27:56,974 - DEBUG - Total memory usage: 102.21875 MB
2022-07-29 12:27:57,539 - DEBUG - Total objects allocated: 438113
                                  types |   # objects |   total size
======================================= | =========== | ============
            pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           2 |     24.61 MB
                                    str |      144600 |     23.60 MB
                                   dict |       40957 |     15.36 MB
                                   code |       36800 |      6.26 MB
                                   type |        5342 |      4.92 MB
                                   list |       31955 |      3.04 MB
                                  tuple |       34692 |      2.01 MB
                                    set |        2222 |      1.42 MB
                          numpy.ndarray |          86 |    752.26 KB
                                weakref |        9220 |    648.28 KB
                collections.OrderedDict |         269 |    459.09 KB
                            abc.ABCMeta |         421 |    453.01 KB
  openpyxl.descriptors.MetaSerialisable |         424 |    440.56 KB
                                    int |       14551 |    426.82 KB
             builtin_function_or_method |        5516 |    387.84 KB
```

This is memory usage after:

```
2022-07-29 12:28:10,295 - DEBUG - Total memory usage: 111.296875 MB
2022-07-29 12:28:10,793 - DEBUG - Total objects allocated: 439022
                                  types |   # objects |   total size
======================================= | =========== | ============
              pandas.core.series.Series |          48 |     24.93 MB
            pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           2 |     24.61 MB
                                    str |      144605 |     23.60 MB
                                   dict |       41326 |     15.42 MB
                                   code |       36800 |      6.26 MB
                                   type |        5342 |      4.92 MB
                                   list |       31998 |      3.04 MB
                                  tuple |       34785 |      2.02 MB
                                    set |        2223 |      1.42 MB
                          numpy.ndarray |         133 |    757.03 KB
                                weakref |        9269 |    651.73 KB
                collections.OrderedDict |         269 |    459.09 KB
                            abc.ABCMeta |         421 |    453.01 KB
  openpyxl.descriptors.MetaSerialisable |         424 |    440.56 KB
                                    int |       14597 |    428.08 KB
```

Comment: use `df.stack().astytpe(str).str.count(...).add(1).gt(SOURCE_WORDS_LIMIT).unstack()`